# How to "grep" for a specific pattern in Windows text file and set it as a variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file, find, findstr

I have a log file that gets downloaded every day that contains a list files on a Windows server.  A portion of the filename changes every day.  I'm trying to write either a batch script or powershell script that can parse the text file, find the filename I'm looking for, and then set it as a variable.

Text file example contents:

```text
filename-v12345.txt
filename-v12346.txt
filename-v12347.txt
filename-v12348.txt
```

Say I want to find the latest file in this list (`filename-v12348.txt`) and set that as a variable.  This is very simple in Linux bash using grep, but I'm rather surprised that I'm having a difficult time with this in Windows. `Find` and `findstr` will pull the entire LINE from the file, but I need JUST the filename to set it as a variable.  I feel like this should be easy, but I'm just not seeing it.  Can someone please slap me up side the head and tell me that I'm missing something simple and show me what I need to do? Thanks.

Comment: you may try to read log file line by line, tokenize it, and than process each single tokens by findstr (as it support simple REGEX).

Comment: If all you need is the last line of the file, you can do `$line = Get-Content file.txt -Last 1` and the `$line` variable will have the value. This is also much faster than to grep through the whole file, as `Get-Content` only needs to scan backwards from the end of the file up to the next newline.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of a working `grep` command that you're looking to implement in PowerShell, ideally along with sample input data (full lines, not just the filenames).

Answer (score 1):

The closest to [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/) you might find on PowerShell would be [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7.2) which can find patterns in *strings*, *arrays of strings* and *files*.

For example, to find the file ending in `v12348\.txt$`:

```
@'
filename-v12345.txt
filename-v12346.txt
filename-v12347.txt
filename-v12348.txt
'@ -split '\r?\n' | Select-String 'v12348\.txt$' | ForEach-Object Line
```

This cmdlet outputs objects of the type [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) which have many properties that may be of interest (the example above only targets the `Line` property):

```
IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 4
Line       : filename-v12348.txt
Filename   : InputStream
Path       : InputStream
Pattern    : .+12348\.txt$
Context    : 
Matches    : {0}
```

If you want to search the pattern in a file you can use the `-LiteralPath` parameter:

```
$match = Select-String -LiteralPath path\to\myfile.ext -Pattern '.+v12348\.txt$'
$match.Line # => Should be the line content where the pattern was matched (`filename-v12348.txt`)
```